# What is best way to move database from Magento 2 to Magento 1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, import

I wanna move product category order from Magento 2 to Magento 1.

what is the best way for this? I create export from product and import to Magento 1 by default tools on manage but I get some error like

> product type does not match and....

so that does not work.

What is **difference between M1 DB and M2 DB** and it impossible to use M2 DB for M1?
Or maybe we move some table between two databases?

Comment: using data migration

Comment: @RkRathod can you give me more details like a link or a name

Comment: i think it is not possible